# Getting error "$ is not defined", what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can someone take a look and tell me why I'm getting this error, why my code isn't working? Thanks!

```js
var jquery = document.createElement("script");
bbbfooter.appendChild(jquery);
jquery.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js");

var byefooter = document.createElement("script");
bbbfooter.appendChild(byefooter);
var byefooters = document.createTextNode("function byeFooter(){$('.bbbfooter').animate({ bottom: -100, duration: 500, queue: false });} $('.clickx').on('click', byeFooter);");
byefooter.appendChild(byefooters);
```

bbbfooter is declared earlier in my code

Comment: Swap lines 2 and 3 so that you configure the `script` before appending it.

Comment: Also, declare that `bbbfooter`

Comment: Thanks for this, seems so obvious now you mention it. Unfortunately it still has the same error and I can't tell why

Answer (score 1):

It takes time for the script to load, and you are trying to use right away.

You'll have to use `setTimeout()` to check when $ is defined and, only then, use jQuery to do whatever you want.

```js
// load jquery

var run_if_jquery_is_defined = function (callback) {
  if ( typeof $ != 'undefined' ) {
    callback();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function () { run_if_jquery_is_defined(callback); }, 50);
  }
};

run_if_jquery_is_defined( function () {
  // your code that needs jquery
} );
```

Comment: `using_underscores_with_all_lower_case_is_valid` but `camelCaseIsMoreCommon`

Comment: Hey, thank you. I'm not getting that error anymore but my jquery still isn't working... powering through

Comment: Try changing this two lines: `callback();` --> `callback($);` and `run_if_jquery_is_defined( function () {` --> `run_if_jquery_is_defined( function ($) {`.